# ЕГАИС в приложении android

Tags: java, c#, android

есть задача завезти списывание алкоголя ЕГАИС в приложение, как это сделать? Есть какое-нибудь api самого ЕГАИСА либо программы которая работает с ним? Можно ли сделать списание через api СторХауз? Мы готовим к запуску приложение автоматизации по типу rkeeper но только со своим уклоном и человек знакомый из кипера сказал что обязательно нужно чтобы было списание алкоголя. Т.е моя программа на C# или с помощью Java плагина должна отправить данные какой-то проге которая работает с ЕГАИС либо мне как-то самостоятельно отправлять инфу в ЕГАИС, я сейчас рассматриваю СторХауз т.к в любом случае делаю с ним интеграцию, было бы славно если через него можно такое сделать, но готов рассмотреть любой вариант. Что посоветуете?

Comment: https://github.com/evotor/egais-api

Comment: Так АПИ это вроде как уже без привязки к конкретному железу или кассам. Да и на гитхабе можно задать вопрос автору репозитория

Comment: А чем существующие решения не нравятся? Я бы рекомендовал не экономить в этом месте, а взять кассу с поддержкой ЕГАИС. Представляете, какие штрафы вас ждут, если возникнет ошибка в вашем приложении. Это финансовая ответственность.

Comment: Да я бы с радостью готовые решения использовал, знать бы какое. Мы готовим к запуску приложение автоматизации по типу rkeeper но только со своим уклоном и человек знакомый из кипера сказал что обязательно нужно чтобы было списание алкоголя. Т.е моя программа на C# или с помощью Java плагина должна отправить данные какой-то проге которая работает с ЕГАИС либо мне как-то самостоятельно отправлять инфу в ЕГАИС, я сейчас рассматриваю СторХауз т.к в любом случае делаю с ним интеграцию, было бы славно если через него можно такое сделать, но готов рассмотреть любой вариант. Что посоветуете?